# Mistake with proof

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs

Is there an error in the following proof?

Proposition: $\forall r \in {N} ; r \neq 1$  , then $\exists$ $n \in {Z}$ such that $$2^{1/n} < r$$

Proof: Let $n$ be any integer with $$n > 1/ log_2 r$$
Then $$1/n < log_2r$$
Hnece $$2^{1/n} < 2^{log_2r} = r$$

Comment: How do you know that such an $n$ does exist? While you give a property, I'd think showing the right hand side as bounded would be useful here.

Comment: It is more clear if you note that $2^{1/2}\lt 2$, which finishes things. However, I believe you want $r$ to be any **real** greater than $1$. In that case your proof, if use of properties of log is allowed, is OK.

Comment: Note that as stated, the result basically does not require proof. You are saying that $r$ is a natural number different from $1$, which means $\ge 2$. You are looking for $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2^{1/n}\lt r$. Well, we can take $n=-1$. And if we correct the $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, we can take $n=2$.